# How do I make the larger child divs to always fit in the parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***Html***

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

***Stylesheet***

```
.child1, .child2, .child3{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.parent{
    height: 200px;
}
```

The child divs may have a height that is larger than 200px but I am not able to figure out how make it fit inside the parent without truncating content of the child div.

Comment: lol, so what is you request then? Use magic to fit an unfittable thing?

Comment: you could use `overflow:auto;` for `.parent` which will make the parent scrollable.

Comment: Static height and dynamic content doesn't mix well... unless you do what @Lal suggests

Comment: `position: relative` on both chldren and parent, maybe?

Comment: @Lal http://jsfiddle.net/60hr1gbe/11/ .In any way is it possible to make the 2 divs of equal height? Without scrolling of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/gngx7q3h/)

As mentioned in my comment, you could use `overflow:auto;` for `.parent` which will make the parent scrollable.

**CSS**

```
.child1,.child2,.child3 {
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
    margin:10px;
}
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

If you want to just the vertical scrollbar, use `overflow-x:auto` for `.parent` instead of `overflow:auto;`

Please see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for more information about `overflow`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow` property on the parent or the children.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

```css
.parent {
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.parent div {
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem Ispum</div>  
  <div>Lorem Ispum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum</div>
</div>
```